# If sum of a set of increasing functions defined on $[a,b]$ is convergent, will this sum be Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

If $\{f_n\}$ is a set of increasing functions defined on $[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} f_n$ converges to $F(x)$, will $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} f_n$ be Lebesgue measurable?

I got this question when I was reading Fubini's Differentiation Theorem. For finite sum, that's correct. But I'm not sure for infinite sum.

Besides, I've no idea of a more general case that is removal of limitation of "increasing" functions, in other words, a set of measurable functions, will this question have the same answer?

Comment: I suppose you want to assume that the $f_n$ are measurable too ;)

Comment: @Tryss: Yes. $f_n$ should be Lebesgue measurable. I think it make no sense on topic of arbitary real value function $f_n$.

Comment: Increasing functions are measurable. The sum of non-decreasing functions is a non-decreasing function.

Comment: @TrialAndError : oh yes, you're right, it's obvious this way.

Comment: @TrialAndError: you mean $S_k = \sum_{n=1}^{k} f_n$ and $S_k$ non-decreasing?

Comment: Yes, $S_{k}(x) \le S_{k}(y)$ for $x \le y$, and the limit inherits this property.

Comment: @Ilham: It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing functions are measurable. Pointwise limits of measurable functions are measurable. Since the sum converges at each point $x$ to a point on the extended real line, try looking at the partial sums, which are measurable.